# Defining Monad, Applicative, and Functor instances for a type class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

Let's say I have defined a type class for Caching computations.

```
trait Cached[F[_], A] {
  def value: F[A]
}
```

Intuitively, `Cached` wraps the computation so we can either evaluate it at run time or load the result from the database instead.

I would like to define Functor, Applicative, and Monad instances for this trait. Using Kind-projector to make my life easier:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
object Cached {

  def apply[F[_], A](f: => F[A]): Cached[F, A] = new Cached[F, A] {
    override def value: F[A] = f
  }

  implicit def functor[F[_] : Functor]: Functor[Cached[F, ?]] = new Functor[Cached[F, ?]] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Cached[F, A])(f: A => B): Cached[F, B] =
      Cached(fa.value map f)
  }

  implicit def applicative[F[_] : Applicative]: Applicative[Cached[F, ?]] = new Applicative[Cached[F, ?]] {
    override def point[A](a: => A): Cached[F, A] = Cached(a.point[F])

    override def ap[A, B](fa: => Cached[F, A])(f: => Cached[F, A => B]): Cached[F, B] =
      Cached(fa.value <*> f.value)
  }

  implicit def monad[F[_] : Monad](implicit app: Applicative[Cached[F, ?]], func: Functor[Cached[F, ?]]): Monad[Cached[F, ?]] =
    new Monad[Cached[F, ?]] {
      override def point[A](a: => A): Cached[F, A] = app.point(a)

      override def bind[A, B](fa: Cached[F, A])(f: A => Cached[F, B]): Cached[F, B] =
        Cached(func.map(fa)(f).value >>= (_.value))
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now, let's use the monad in a simple example:

```
import Cached._
val y = Cached(2.point[Id])
val z = for {
  a <- Cached(1.point[Id])
  b <- y
} yield a + b
```

Running the code, I get the following error at run time:

```
[error] diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Applicative[[β$4$]Cached[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,β$4$]]
[error] starting with method monad in object Cached
[error]       a <- Cached(1.point[Id])
[error]                  ^
[error] diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Applicative[[β$4$]Cached[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,β$4$]]
[error] starting with method monad in object Cached
[error]       b <- y
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I know diverging implicit expansion happens when the compiler stuck in a loop when expanding the implicit definitions, but I can't see why that is the case with my code.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction. I am pretty new to functional programming concepts so what I have done here might not even make sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining the instances like this:

```
implicit def instance[F[_] : Monad]: Functor[Cached[F, ?]] with Applicative[Cached[F, ?]] with Monad[Cached[F, ?]] =
    new Functor[Cached[F, ?]] with Applicative[Cached[F, ?]] with Monad[Cached[F, ?]] {
      def eval[A](fa: => Cached[F, A]): F[A] = {
        println("loading stuff from the database...")
        fa.value
      }

      override def point[A](a: => A): Cached[F, A] =
        Cached(a.point[F])

      override def map[A, B](fa: Cached[F, A])(f: A => B): Cached[F, B] = {
        Cached(eval(fa) map f)
      }

      override def bind[A, B](fa: Cached[F, A])(f: A => Cached[F, B]): Cached[F, B] = {
        Cached(eval(fa) >>= (a => f(a).value))
      }

      override def ap[A, B](fa: => Cached[F, A])(f: => Cached[F, A => B]): Cached[F, B] =
        Cached(eval(fa) <*> f.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler doesn't know whether your method `point` refers to the `applicative` one or the `monad` one.

Monad typeclasses are often made to extend Applicatives, since every monad really is an applicative functor (plus the "join", known in Scala as "flatten"). If you want to avoid hierarchies and would like both your monads and applicatives to define their own `point`, then you need to either name them differently or somehow tell the compiler which one you're referring to (e.g. via type parameter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no problem defining hierarchies. I was under the impression that implicit parameter `app` and `func` passed to the monad instance will make sure that the `point` in monad will be the same as the `point` in applicative.
I followed the example here https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html when defining these instances.

Comment: You have both the applicative and monad available as a valid implicit conversion. `app` and `func` contribute to the fact that monad conversion is valid (if one of them were missing, the conversion wouldn't be applied). So both applicative and monad try to kick in. The reason why cats don't have that problem in their doc is bcs they only define the monad implicit conversion (which piggybacks on the existing applicative typeclass). There is no applicative implicit conversion in their code.